# In an undirected graph, is $(u,v) = (v,u)$?

Tags: graph-theory

Lets say we have an undirected graph $G=\langle V,E\rangle$, such that $ (u,v),(v,k)\in E$.

Does the path from $u$ to $k$ can be represented as $\{(u,v),(v,k)\}$ and also as $\{(v,u),(k,v)\}$? Or do they represent different paths?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are 3 vertices: u,v,k in an undirected graph G, and there's an edge between u-v, and v-k.  
I simply ask if I can represent the path from u to k in 2 different ways, or if they represent different paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they represent the same path, since in an undirected graph you have that if $(u,v) \in E$ then $(v,u) \in E$ and specifically $(u,v)=(v,u)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the definition of "undirected" is for any edge(u,v): (u,v) = (v,u).

For the "path" part, I think it depends on how you define "path".